# How can i use constructor in django admin for model

Tags: python, django

I am using django admin for my site.
I have the class Student and Admin is automatically generating the form.

now i want to initilaize the value of location in Student Model itself based on the logged in user location.

I don't want to do in form but in model something like

```
class Student:

   def __init__(self):
       self.location = get_logged_user_location()
```

Is it possible to do like this in Mdel only

i am trying like this

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Student, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name="test"
```

but its not working. i am getting empty text field in form

Comment: why not put default in your name field. `name = models.CharField(default=get_logged_user_location())`

Comment: Models can be used outside the request/response phase (from django shell for instance), which won't necessarily allow you to have access to a request or a user. The place to be setting data is within a form, or possibly with your Admin models.

Comment: Actually if i do that i need to run the database migrations and i don't want to do that. is there any way to do that in constructor

Comment: You make it complicated. You can initialize the value using modelforms

Answer (score 0):

**should be:**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name="test"
    super(Student, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```